# Laravel, using packages with PSR-4 gives message "No hint path defined for"

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, psr-4

Im using Laravel 4.1 and starting a package (subby) that is using PSR-4 standard.
When I try to render any view with:

```
return View::make('subby::user.login');
```

I get the message:

```
No hint path defined for [subby]
```

I've red many things, but those were usually typo problems

Comment: With Laravel 5 this not longer makes sense

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The problem is in the usage of the PSR-4
Since Laravel default is PSR-0 it assumes that the resources (views etc) of a package will be 2 levels up from where the package service provider is. Ex:

```
src
├── config
├── lang
├── migrations
├── Ghunti
│   └── Subby
│       └── SubbyServiceProvider.php
├── routes.php
└── views
    └── user
        └── login.blade.php
```

With PSR-4 the package service provider and the views will be at the same level (and the error "No hint path defined for" will show up:

```
src
├── config
├── lang
├── migrations
├── SubbyServiceProvider.php
├── routes.php
└── views
    └── user
        └── login.blade.php
```

To fix this, on the package service provider `boot()` method, instead of:

```
public function boot()
{
    $this->package('ghunti/subby');
}
```

we need to specify the resources path (the 3rd parameter)

```
public function boot()
{
    //For PSR-4 compatibility we need to specify the correct path (3rd parameter)
    $this->package('ghunti/subby', null, __DIR__);
}
```