# Laravel 5: No hint path defined for [Auth]

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I'm loading view for mail

```
$this->mail->send('auth::emails.email_confirmation', ['url' => $confirmationEmailUrl], function ($m) use ($user,  $toMail) {
            $m->to($toMail, $user->name)->subject('mail');
        });
```

And Service Provider

```
 public function registerViews()
    {
        $viewPath = base_path('resources/views/modules/auth');

        $sourcePath = __DIR__ . '/../Resources/views';

        $this->publishes([
            $sourcePath => $viewPath
        ]);

        $this->loadViewsFrom([$viewPath, $sourcePath], 'auth');
    }
```

Note: I'm using pingpong module structure.

Any idea. I'm getting

> No hint path defined for [Auth]

error message. what's problem with this?

Comment: No... because you haven't told US what the problem is! What is the issue?

Comment: @jeff I'm getting "No hint path defined for [Auth]" error message

Comment: Are you using Laravel 4?  Check out this similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22135765/laravel-using-packages-with-psr-4-gives-message-no-hint-path-defined-for

Comment: @jeff I'm using laravel 5. I already checked that but no luck.

Comment: `$this->mail->send('auth::emails.email_confirmation'`

Maybe your problem the first parameter you send to the Mail function? I mean,I don't use Auth:: in there, only the path of the views in this case `emails.email_confirmation`

Comment: Why you were using `send('auth::` instead simply use `send('emails.email_confirmation`

Comment: @Uchiha auth is my module name

Comment: You don't need to use `auth::` over here, [the first parameter within `Mail::send()` is for passing the view](https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/mail#basic-usage) simply remove that `auth::` from that part

Comment: @Uchiha I tried Now i showing error View [emails.new_email_confirmation] not found.

Comment: Did you have that blade within your `resources/views/emails/` created.

Comment: Yes ,I have my views under Auth module resources/views/emails/

Comment: But why within `auth` module and not at the root level

Comment: The folder structure for pingpong is like that http://sky.pingpong-labs.com/docs/2.0/modules#folder-structure

Answer (score 3):

Try giving your service another key instead of "auth". Laravel uses that key and you might be running into conflicts.

```
public function registerViews()
{
    $viewPath = base_path('resources/views/modules/auth');

    $sourcePath = __DIR__ . '/../Resources/views';

    $this->publishes([
        $sourcePath => $viewPath
    ]);

    $this->loadViewsFrom([$viewPath, $sourcePath], 'my-auth');
}
```

Then try

```
$this->mail->send('my-auth::emails.email_confirmation', ['url' => $confirmationEmailUrl], function ($m) use ($user,  $toMail) {
    $m->to($toMail, $user->name)->subject('mail');
});
```

Comment: No luck . Same error. No hint path defined for [Auth].

Comment: Can you include your updated code and the full stack trace that's in your error log?

Answer (score 2):

The error isn't in the code you've shown us. The error states there is no hint path for `Auth`, with a capital "A". Somewhere in your code, you have tried to access a view using the `Auth::` prefix, instead of `auth::`.

This is further evidenced by the fact that you attempted @PatrickStephan's solution, but the error message did not change.

You need to find where you did this and correct the case.